# RedBlack Tree Implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I've implemented a red-black tree and then inserted `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10` in it. But it seems that my tree is not balanced because the pre-order traverse looks like this: `4,2,1,3,6,5,8,7,9,10` and the in-order traverse: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`. And that means the root is `4` and the tree is not balanced! Here is my code.

```
void RedBlackTree::leftRotate(RedBlackTreeNode * x){
    RedBlackTreeNode *y = x->right; //set y
    y = x->right;
    x->right = y->left;
    if (y->left != nilLeaf)
        y->left->p = x;
    y->p = x->p;
    if (x->p == nilLeaf)
        root = y;
    else if (x == x->p->left)
        x->p->left = y;
    else x->p->right = y;
    y->left = x;
    x->p = y;
}

void RedBlackTree::rightRotate(RedBlackTreeNode * x){
    RedBlackTreeNode *y = x->left; //set y
    y = x->left;
    x->left = y->right;
    if (y->right != nilLeaf)
        y->right->p = x;
    y->p = x->p;
    if (x->p == nilLeaf)
        root = y;
    else if (x == x->p->right)
        x->p->right = y;
    else x->p->left = y;
    y->right = x;
    x->p = y;
}

void RedBlackTree::insert(const Point &newItem){
    size++;
    if (empty){
        root->key = newItem;
        empty = false;
        return;
    }

    RedBlackTreeNode * z = new RedBlackTreeNode; 
    z->key = newItem;
    z->right = z->left = z->p = nilLeaf;

    RedBlackTreeNode *y = nilLeaf;// = new RedBlackTreeNode;
    RedBlackTreeNode *x = root;// = new RedBlackTreeNode;

    while (x != nilLeaf)
    {
        y = x;
        if (z->key < x->key)
            x = x->left;
        else
            x = x->right;
    }
    z->p = y;
    if (y == nilLeaf)
        root = z;
    else if (z->key < y->key)
        y->left = z;
    else
        y->right = z;

    z->left = nilLeaf;
    z->right = nilLeaf;
    z->color = RedBlackTreeNode::Red;

    insertFixUp(z);
}

void RedBlackTree::insertFixUp(RedBlackTreeNode* z){
    while (z->p->color == RedBlackTreeNode::Red)
    {
        if (z->p == z->p->p->left)
        {
            RedBlackTreeNode* y = z->p->p->right;
            if (y->color == RedBlackTreeNode::Red)
            {
                z->p->color = RedBlackTreeNode::Black;
                y->color = RedBlackTreeNode::Black;
                z->p->p->color = RedBlackTreeNode::Red;
                z = z->p->p;
            }
            else if (z == z->p->right)
            {
                z = z->p;
                leftRotate(z);
            }
            else{
                z->p->color = RedBlackTreeNode::Black;
                z->p->p->color = RedBlackTreeNode::Red;
                rightRotate(z->p->p);
            }
        }
        else if (z->p == z->p->p->right)
        {
            RedBlackTreeNode* y = z->p->p->left;
            if (y->color == RedBlackTreeNode::Red)
            {
                z->p->color = RedBlackTreeNode::Black;
                y->color = RedBlackTreeNode::Black;
                z->p->p->color = RedBlackTreeNode::Red;
                z = z->p->p;
            }
            else if (z == z->p->left)
            {
                z = z->p;
                rightRotate(z);                             //**
            }
            else{
                z->p->color = RedBlackTreeNode::Black;
                z->p->p->color = RedBlackTreeNode::Red;
                leftRotate(z->p->p);                        //**
            }
        }
    }
    root->color = RedBlackTreeNode::Black;
}
```

But I'm pretty sure that there is something wrong with `insertFixUp`. Because this code works fine for most examples, But for some cases (like above example) the difference between node heights will be greater than two.

**EDIT:** This code works just fine if I insert some random numbers in it, The problem arise when I insert sorted numbers in it.

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with a debugger to see what is going on?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to use MSVS debugger.  Iv tried to print each state using cerr, But I couldn't find the problem. @NathanOliver

Comment: @MoNo You're gonna have to learn someday, and I suggest you do so now.
Try putting a breakpoint and pressing f10/f11 a couple of times. Try hovering some variable names to see their values.
Be sure to compile in debug mode!

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx).  Learning how to step through code is a very important programming skill.

Comment: I think your implementation is fine. Take a look at [visualisation](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/RedBlack.html) of a red/black tree. Try to add numbers from your example and your root will be 4. If you still think you implementation has mistakes, add more details in your question (at least full code for `RedBlackTree` class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this code. According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree):

'These constraints enforce a critical property of red–black trees: that the path from the root to the furthest leaf is no more than twice as long as the path from the root to the nearest leaf. The result is that the tree is roughly height-balanced'

So there is nothing wrong with 4 being the root. Try to insert more numbers in your tree and you will see, the root will change and the mentioned property would always hold.